# Does baseband signal has negative frequency?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, modulation

Does baseband signal has negative frequency? In wiki baseband signal means that can include frequencies that are very near zero. I wonder whether baseband signal has negative frequency.

Thank your answers..

Comment: yes. search for "negative frequencies" on this site, you get plenty of information. If you're researching this at the beginning of a course on communications engineering, just keep reading the course material: the representability of negative frequencies in complex baseband is the very basis for (nearly) all of modern communications technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a signal is real valued, then it will have negative frequencies when represented by complex-exponential Fourier transforms.

But if you use the trigonometric Fourier series representation you do not need a negative frequency concept.

If the signal is complex valued, such as an analytic signal, it may or may not have negative frequencies when represented by complex-exponential Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to watch my YouTube video explaining negative frequency: https://youtu.be/gz6AKW-R69s

I'm a professor and I've been building what I think of as an on-line video textbook for Signals, Systems, and Digital Communications.

Comment: It's quite strange that people react to the concept of *negative frequency*, as if the concepts of **negative length** (as suggested by a cartesian coordinate system), or **negative area** (as suggested by an integral of a function) are very natural and physical. When it's negative length or negative area, people quite agree with the convention that they are **mathematical** abstractions and not of physical relevance. But then we stilll have to explain the physical significance of the negative frequency to those skeptical minds... :-)))

Comment: As well as the **negative temperature**...! :-) Have you ever had a student objecting to negative Fahrenheits? No they can't exist because negative molecular kinetic energy cannot exist.. :-)

Comment: You're right. I've never thought about it like that. I guess a difference is that all the things you listed are measured from a reference (length, temperature in Fahrenheits, etc), but frequency is measured from absolute zero (ie. zero oscillations), so it's a different concept to think of "negative oscillations". It would be like trying to think of negative temperature measured in Kelvin - it the particles stop moving at zero Kelvin, then what does negative Kelvin mean?

Comment: Yes that's one part of the answer, (however, a signed **area** is not measured from a reference?) And for the *oscillations*, I think we have a *clockwise* vs *counter-clockwise* reference to differentiate between them. Nevertheless, despite I'm not sure about the negative Kelvins (which I believe do not exist), it could be the temperatue of a negative mass gas ? :-) (or a positive mass with imaginary speeds)